# What part of installed RAM can be used at maximum?

Tags: memory

Yesterday I added 4 GB RAM to my Acer 5749z

http://www.cnet.com/products/acer-aspire-5749z-4809-15-6-pentium-b960-windows-7-home-premium-64-bit-4-gb-ram-500-gb-hdd/specs/

so it now is tottaly 8 GB.

I was not sure should I add or not. Actually often these days 8 GB is standard. But I never see in task manager that it would use full of those 4 GB. It was like 3.xx always maximum.

Now with 8 GB I opened few applications which I ussually was opening with 4 GB RAM, and I see that it shows 4.10 GB usage.

Maybe it is not capable of using 100% of the RAM. So then the maximum value is some other % I guess. **But how do I know what is the maximum value?** Then I would see I reached maximum, and my pc needs upgrade. This pc does not support more, but I mean in general I would like to understand.

For example some day I will reach the maximum of those 8 GB (or maybe even today, I did not give full load to my pc yet). But I will be not sure when it is - because it will also not use full of 8 GB most likely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like you're trying to run a 32 bit application, which (without "cheating" by the operating system) won't be able to address more than 4 GB memory in total. That's a fixed limit and essentially the maximum. However, within that availalbe address space, the OS has to reserve other kinds of memory addresses as well, for example the available video memory of your graphics card or some memory areas provided by other hardware (like a sound card). Otherwise the program's code wouldn't be able to write there, since it wouldn't be able to reach that memory.

There's no way around this limit, since your program obviously is "large address aware" already, which allows it to use up to 3.xx GB rather than the 2 GB older 32 bit programs were limited to.

64 bit programs will be able to use more than those 3.x GB (theoretically up to 8 GB).

To see the total amount of RAM installed (and detected/utilized by Windows), simply hit <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Break</kbd>. Under "System" it will list the amount of RAM installed/used.

Comment: When I hit win + Break I see 8 GB and 7.85 GB ussable. So I will be able to reach 7.85 and see it in task manager, right? And when I reach this, I can consider buying new computer if I cannot live with that because I will know that it is using full possible memory.

Comment: No, you shouldn't have to buy a new computer just because you hit that limit. Memory is dynamic and having 8 GB of RAM simply means that your computer can keep a working set of 8 GB in total "ready and accessible". Your operating system (here: Windows) will be able to swap unused areas of memory to your hard disk to increase the available memory. So in theory, even though you've got only 8 GB installed, your programs might in total use 8 GB, 9 GB, or even 16+ GB. This will have a negative impact on performance though.

Comment: Yea, what I meant is performance, and I know that it will start using hard disk if it is not enough, thats what was happening with 4 GB of RAM. But 7.85 GB is reachable in my case, right?

Comment: Yes, you'll be able to use up to ~7.85 GB without significant use of the swap file (don't disable it; Windows will still use it to improve performance).